# Azure function not able to read the data from CosmosDB using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to deploy the Azure function inside the function app and trying to read the data in the Azure function from CosmosDB.

The code is not able to fetch the data from the CosmosDB in the az-cli deployed function but if the same function I am running locally it is able to fetch the data properly.

If we deploy the Azure function using the VS code then it works properly.

Code snippet for fetching the data.

```
def getting_meta_data(nodecellid):
    logging.info('inside getting meta data function')
    logging.info('---------- %s',nodecellid)
    logging.info(type(nodecellid))
    endpoint = 'https://subscription-cosmosdb.documents.azure.com:443/'
    key = 'key'
    client = CosmosClient(endpoint, key)

    # Connect to the database and container
    container_name = 'container-name'
    database_name = 'database-name'
    database = client.get_database_client(database_name)
    container = database.get_container_client(container_name)
    
    data_dict = {}
    logging.info("&&&&& %s",nodecellid)
    for item in container.query_items(
                    query = f"SELECT * FROM r WHERE r['NodeCellId'] = '{nodecellid}'",
                    enable_cross_partition_query=True):
        print(item)
        data_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(item, indent=True))
        logging.info("++++++++",json.dumps(item, indent=True))  
    logging.info("//////",'meta-data value %s',data_dict) 
    
    logging.info('completed meta-data ')
    if data_dict == {}:
        logging.info('empty meta-data)
        return -1
    return data_dict


nodecellid = 'nodecellid'
getting_meta_data(nodecellid)
```

When I am trying to fetch the data from cosmosDB using the VS deployed function it is able to fetch the code even though the content of both functions (one deployed using VS code and one deployed using azure function code-tools)

Both function code contains the same code but they have some difference, which I will mention below.

```
VS code deployed code
**__init.py__** file which contains the code
**function.json** - which contains the binding details to the Azure function.
**sample.dat**
**readme.md**

Azure func core tools deployed code
**function_app.py** file which contains the code
**host.json** - Function App settings
**oryx-manifest.toml**
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong for this.

The same code is working locally and on VS code deployed Azure function but not in func core-tools deployed Azure function.

I am attaching the logs for more information.

```
Result: Failure Exception: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 493, in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 762, in _run_sync_func return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context, File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper result = function(**args) File "/home/site/wwwroot/function_app.py", line 45, in ChronosAzureFunction tagging(blob_client) File "/home/site/wwwroot/function_app.py", line 147, in tagging getting_meta_data(nodecellid_test) File "/home/site/wwwroot/function_app.py", line 369, in getting_meta_data logging.info("++++++++",json.dumps(item, indent=True)) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 2097, in info root.info(msg, *args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1446, in info self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1589, in _log self.handle(record) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1599, in handle self.callHandlers(record) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers hdlr.handle(record) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 952, in handle self.emit(record) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 829, in emit msg = self.format(record) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 927, in format return fmt.format(record) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 663, in format record.message = record.getMessage() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 367, in getMessage msg = msg % self.args
```

Comment: Please do not create clients within Function execution: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections?tabs=csharp#static-clients, you will run into port and instance limit issues.

Comment: What is the trigger of the Function?

Comment: My function is blob triggered.

Comment: Can you clarify what "code is not able to fetch the data" means? Does the query fail with an error? Does the query not provide any results? Is the Cosmos DB account used in both working/non-working the same?

Comment: the query is correct, and yes in working and non-working cosmodb is the same

Result: Failure Exception: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

This is the error I am getting,

Comment: @RavikantGautam In VS Code you created with python v1 model but in Azure CLI it is created with python v2 model. You need to change the code accordingly for the v2 model.

Comment: Please attach the TypeError exception you are getting with full details, this is a critical piece that is not mentioned or included in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed code to Azure using **CLI** and works fine in my Azure Portal. I followed below steps:

**Sample data:**

[image]

- I tried with below code in my local machine which works successfully.

```py
def getting_meta_data(nodecellid):
    logging.info('inside getting meta data function')
    logging.info('---------- %s', nodecellid)
    logging.info('Type of nodecellid: %s', type(nodecellid))

    endpoint = '*****'
    key = '*****'
    client = CosmosClient(endpoint, key)

   
    container_name = 'SecondCont'
    database_name = 'NewDb'
    database = client.get_database_client(database_name)
    container = database.get_container_client(container_name)

    data_dict = {}
    logging.info("&&&&& %s", nodecellid)

    for item in container.query_items(
        query=f"SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.NodeCellId = '{nodecellid}'",
        enable_cross_partition_query=True):
        data_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(item, indent=True))
        print(data_dict)
        logging.info("++++++++ %s", json.dumps(item, indent=True))

    logging.info("////// meta-data value %s", data_dict)

    logging.info('completed meta-data')

    if not data_dict:
        logging.info('empty meta-data')
        return -1

    return data_dict

@app.blob_trigger(arg_name="myblob", path="mycontainer/", connection="BlobStorageConnectionString") 
def blob_trigger(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob")
    nodecellid = 'nodecellid1'
    getting_meta_data(nodecellid)
```

- I converted my project folder into zip folder and uploaded into the Azure Cloud Environment.
  [image]
- Below is the command i used to deploy into the azure function app.

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <your resource group> -n oct31func --src pythonBlobProj.zip
```

**Deployment Status:**
[image]

[image]

- Click on `blob_trigger` and click `Code + Test` to run the code.
  [image]
- Check the final status of retrieving the data from Cosmos DB in monitor.
  [image]